# ISS url rewriting pattern

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, routes

I want to create Url rewriting pattern in ISS. I want when url has %2c% it will convert %2c% to " , ".

Input :www.example.com/videos/video1%2c%video2%2c%video3%2c%video4%2c% Output:www.example.com/videos/video1,video2,video3,vide4

How can i do that. In picture is as follow. Its example of url rewriting screen in iis.
[image: iss url rewriting]

Comment: Can you give a better example of your required input and output values, as that'll help write a more accurate pattern.

Comment: Input :www.example.com/videos/video1%2c%video2%2c%video3%2c%video4%2c%
Output:www.example.com/videos/video1,video2,video3,vide4